# Why I get exception when I call stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SPDeleteRegion
      @siteId int,
      @regionId int 
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @isDeleted BIT 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SiteObjects WHERE SiteRegionId = @regionId)
    BEGIN
        SET @isDeleted = 0 ; --not deleted
        RETURN @isDeleted;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --do what needs to be done if not       
        DELETE FROM SiteRegions 
        WHERE Id = @regionId;

        SET @isDeleted = 1;  -- deleted
        RETURN @isDeleted;
    END
END
```

Here how I call the stored procedure in C#:

```
var t = _context.Database.SqlQuery<bool>("SPDeleteRegion @siteId, @regionId",
                                          new SqlParameter("@siteId", siteId),
                                          new SqlParameter("@regionId", regionId));
```

On the line of code above I get this exception:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Any idea why I get the excewption and how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you specify `bool` as a type parameter `_context.Database.SqlQuery<bool>`? Your procedure does not return anything

Comment: Dosen't it returns this: @isDeleted;

Comment: I am using Oracle. In Oracle if you want to return something from procedure, you have specify it at procedure declaration as output parameter. Is not it true for other databases? You have not declared `isDeleted` at procedure declaration.

Comment: The **return** value of a stored procedure in SQL Server is **always** an `INT` (or bigint) - typically it signals how many rows were affected by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operation. You **cannot** send back a `bit` using the `RETURN` keyword - you need to use either an `OUTPUT` parameter, or you need to select your `bit` and thus return a result set

Comment: @marc_s why it returns -1 if no rows was effected?

Comment: If nothing was deleted - then yes, I would expect -1 as the return value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure doesn't selecting anything. Change it like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SPDeleteRegion
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
      @siteId int,
      @regionId int 
AS
BEGIN 
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE 
    @isDeleted BIT 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SiteObjects WHERE SiteRegionId = @regionId)
    BEGIN
        SET @isDeleted = 0 ; --not deleted
        SELECT @isDeleted [IsDeleted]; --HERE
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --do what needs to be done if not       
        DELETE FROM SiteRegions WHERE Id = @regionId;
        SET @isDeleted = 1;--deleted
        SELECT @isDeleted [IsDeleted]; -- AND HERE
    END
END
```